# Traversing a tree in ascending generation order

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

First I want to know if this is a well-defined operation:  We first visit all the leaves of the tree (from left to right).  Then we visit all the parents of the leaves (from left to right).  Then all the parents of those parents, etc... until the last unvisited node is visited.  Note that the root is not necessarily the last visited node.  If a certain parent has already been visited, we simply ignore it.  I can't think of a counter-example where this traversal will fail.

So assuming it is well-defined.  What would be the most efficient algorithm to make this traversal?  For simplicity of the pseudocode, we can assume it is a binary tree.  Getting all the leaves first is already time-consuming.  But in the meantime we can extract with each successive parent by storing the parents somewhere as we obtain the leaves.  Then we visit these lists of parents, each list being one generation higher in the tree than the previous list.  Something like that?  I only know c++ unfortunately, but can figure out a pseudocode in other languages.

Getting all the leaves of a binary tree (tested):

```
template <typename T, typename Comparator>
inline void BinaryTree<T, Comparator>::obtainLeaves (const std::shared_ptr<Node>& node,
std::list<std::shared_ptr<Node>>& leaves) const {
    if (!node)
        return;
    if (node->isLeaf())
        return leaves.emplace_back(node);
    obtainLeaves(node->left, leaves);
    obtainLeaves(node->right, leaves);
}
```

Though the leaves' parents can easily be stored from this with that list of parents passed around, what about all the successive parents?

```
template <typename T, typename Comparator>
inline void BinaryTree<T, Comparator>::obtainLeaves (const std::shared_ptr<Node>& node,
std::list<std::shared_ptr<Node>>& leaves, std::set<std::shared_ptr<Node>>& parents) const {
    if (!node)
        return;
    if (node->isLeaf()) {
        leaves.emplace_back(node);
        parents.emplace(node->parent);
        return;
    }
    obtainLeaves(node->left, leaves, parents);
    obtainLeaves(node->right, leaves, parents);
}
```

Or instead of doing it all in one shot, first get the leaves.  Then iterate the list of leaves to obtain their parents by calling `->parent`.  Then repeat the process with those parents, and so forth.  But that seems very clumsy and time-consuming to me, and also does not really check for repeats very well.

Comment: How about storing extra fields in the tree and in nodes themselves while building the tree to facilitate this? Are we working under the assumption that we are given a tree and has to traverse it and can't expect to have any special fields?

Comment: @ThomasG   The tree's structure itself can be modified.  I thought that a `parent` member was the only new useful member that we can add to each node.  What other member would facilitate this?

Comment: We can add a 'LeftMostNode' to the tree during the build phase. We can also add, for example sibling pointers. Then instead of starting the traversal at root, we can start at the left most node and follow the sibling pointers. That way, we can increase the ratio (number of leaf nodes visited / number of their parents visited) in the first pass. Basically space vs. speed tradeoff. For some reason SO wouldn't allow me to add @prestokeys at the beginning of this comment !!

Comment: @ThomasG   `leftmostNode` sounds like an idea but as for `siblings`, the parents of two leaves need not be siblings.  In fact a parent of a leaf can be the parent of another parent of a leaf.  Similarly, grandparents of leaves need not be siblings.  Unless by siblings you mean some other complex type of layering.

Comment: Yes, the sibling links won't make visiting the parent nodes totally unnecessary, those visits are still required at least in some cases. By siblings, I simply meant as normally understood, sharing a parent, nothing complex. To perfectly achieve the goal of traversing purely one level at a time, we may need many more links maintained and updated during build phase. This question may have practical application in XPath/XSLT parsers. I wonder how they solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Easy and correct solution:

Build an upside down tree.  As you traverse, maintain a set of back-links toward the root.

Create a vector of the leaves.  As you do so, record their pointer values in a hash map.  Now walk them.

Now, for each element in that vector, replace it with its parent.  And add it to the hash map.  If that is already in the hash map, instead omit it.

Repeat until you run out of parents.

This is probably not optimal.

Comment: A google search on upside down tree turned up nothing.  What are the members of an upside-down tree?  Its leaves?  And each node has a `parent` member only, and no children?

Comment: @prestokeys Yes, keep track of each node's parent.  There are many ways to do that; make an unordered map from node to parent, have_I_visited bool for example.

Answer (score 0):

The following I tested out to work correctly.  I don't know how its time-complexity compares with Yakk's solution though, or even what its time complexity is for that matter.  I do know that every non-leaf node is being visited at least twice here though, which is not a good thing.

```
template <typename T, typename Comparator>
template <typename F, typename... Args>
inline void BinaryTree<T, Comparator>::traverseUpwards (F f, Args&&... args) const {
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<Node>> leaves;
    const std::size_t N = heightOfTree();
    std::vector<std::list<std::shared_ptr<Node>>> parents(N);
    std::set<std::shared_ptr<Node>> alreadyVisited;
    traverseUpwards(root, leaves, parents, alreadyVisited);
    for (const std::shared_ptr<Node>& node : leaves)
        f(node, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (const std::shared_ptr<Node>& node : parents[i])
            f(node, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}

template <typename T, typename Comparator>
inline void BinaryTree<T, Comparator>::traverseUpwards (const std::shared_ptr<Node>& node,
std::list<std::shared_ptr<Node>>& leaves,
std::vector<std::list<std::shared_ptr<Node>>>& parents,
std::set<std::shared_ptr<Node>>& alreadyVisited) const {
    if (!node)
        return;
    if (node->isLeaf()) {  // e.g. (!node->left && !node->right) for a binary tree.
        leaves.emplace_back(node);
        std::shared_ptr<Node> p = node->parent;
        std::size_t i = 0;
        while (p && alreadyVisited.find(p) == alreadyVisited.end()) {
            parents[i++].emplace_back(p);
            alreadyVisited.emplace(p);
            p = p->parent;
        }
    }
    traverseUpwards(node->left, leaves, parents, alreadyVisited);
    traverseUpwards(node->right, leaves, parents, alreadyVisited);
}

template <typename T, typename Comparator>
inline int BinaryTree<T, Comparator>::heightOfTree (const std::shared_ptr<Node>& node) const {
    return node ? std::max (heightOfTree(node->left), heightOfTree(node->right)) + 1 : -1;
}
```